# How to determine whether click happened on element's scrollbar or on its content

Tags: javascript, dom

There is indeed method element.[componentFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536375(VS.85).aspx)(iCoordX, iCoordY) in Internet Explorer, but how do I differentiate a mouse click occurred in the content area of an element from the click occurred on its scrollbar in other browsers?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the same problem using the WebBrowser control in .NET

Answer (score 3):

In **Gecko**-based browser it is possible to check on [`event.originalTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.originalTarget). If click happened on element's scrollbar this property will have a `XULElement` object returned.

**WebKit** and **Presto** to go...

Comment: I did not know that. Have been looking for a solution to this for years.

Comment: @Sergey Ilinsky: if this is the answer to your question, please accept your own answer with clicking the green tick! :) Thanks!

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I can't as the answer only covered solution in one browser.